# Trying to find the first value in each line and print same values together

Tags: python, inheritance, superclass

I am trying to collapse everything together through subclasses and parentclass and print the textfile properly.

I have assigned values for each subclass when printing, how do I tell python to find it and combine every line with the same value (like my output)

I have tried putting i_car & d_car inside the for loop but it still dosen't work so I am assuming it is my argument in the if statement and then put the assignments inside the for loop.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, brand, model, year, price, type):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.price = price
        self.type = type

    def print_info(self):
        print(self.brand, self.model, self.year, self.price, self.type)


class ImportCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, brand, model, year, price, type, country, tax):
        super().__init__(brand, model, year, price, type)
        self.country = country
        self.tax = tax

    def print_info(self):
        print(self.brand, self.model, self.year, self.price, self.type, self.country, self.tax)


class DomesticCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, brand, model, year, price, type, state):
        super().__init__(brand, model, year, price, type)
        self.state = state

    def print_info(self):
        print(self.brand, self.model, self.year, self.price, self.type, self.state)

with open("carsInStock.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        val = line.split()
        i_car = ImportCar(val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3], val[4], val[5], val[6])
        d_car = DomesticCar(val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3], val[4], val[5])
        for i in range(len(val)):
            if val[0] == "I":
                print("Lines starting with I: ", i_car.print_info())
                break;
            elif val[0] == "D":
                print("Lines starting with D: ", d_car.print_info())
                break;
            else:
                print("Error")
```

Textfile:

```
D Ford F150 2012 17000 Truck MI
I Toyota Camry 2014 20000 Sedan Japan 10
D Chrysler Pacifica 2013 18000 Sedan TX
I BMW 325i 2013 30000 Sedan Germany 8
D Chevrolet TahoeLS 2010 7000 Coup TX
D Chevrolet Silverado 2011 10000 Van MI
I Toyota LexusRX30 2015 42000 Sedan Japan 10
D Ford Econoline 2012 16000 Sedan MI
```

Desired output:

```
Lines starting with I:
Toyota Camry 2014 2000 Sedan Japan 10%
BMW 325i 2013 30000 Sedan Germany 8%
Toyota LexusRX30 2015 42000 Sedan Japan 10%

Lines starting with D:
Ford F150 2012 17000 Truck MI
Chrysler Pacifica 2013 18000 Sedan TX
Chevrolet TahoeLS 2010 7000 Coup TX
Chevrolet Silverado 2011 10000 Van MI
Ford Econoline 2012 16000 Sedan MI

Number of I cars = 3
Number of D cars = 5
Total = 8
```

Output right now:

```
D Ford F150 2012 17000 Truck
Lines starting with D:  None
I Toyota Camry 2014 20000 Sedan Japan
Lines starting with I:  None
D Chrysler Pacifica 2013 18000 Sedan
Lines starting with D:  None
I BMW 325i 2013 30000 Sedan Germany
Lines starting with I:  None
D Chevrolet TahoeLS 2010 7000 Coup
Lines starting with D:  None
D Chevrolet Silverado 2011 10000 Van
Lines starting with D:  None
I Toyota LexusRX30 2015 42000 Sedan Japan
Lines starting with I:  None
D Ford Econoline 2012 16000 Sedan
Lines starting with D:  None
```

Comment: Your output is of a *single car*, with a brand of "D Ford F150 2012 17000 Truck MI", a model of "I Toyota Camry 2014 20000 Sedan Japan 10", and so on.  You would need to loop over the lines of the file, and split each one into its component fields.

Comment: As @jasonharper pointed out, `f.readlines()` returns a list of _lines_. You can split each line `l` into pieces using `l.split()`.   Once you do that, you'll need to inspect the results to see if it's a Domestic or Import, and build a separate collection for each type of car.  To generate the aggregated outputs, you should only call the `print_info()` statements once you're done processing the entire file.

Comment: @SarahMesser appreciate you both. Would you take a look at my edit and explain what do I set my if else argument as, because it cant be just "val[0]", pretty sure im missing something.

Comment: You should have the `i_car` and `d_car` assignments inside the loop.  Each `i` in that loop is going to be a separate car. Also, you don't need the `break`.  The `if..elif..else` construction already means "only do one of these things"

Comment: @SarahMesser thank you for getting back to me, even if I move the assignments inside the loop it still not recognizing between lines starting with *D* or *I*

Comment: Please update the current output.  Make sure you correctly pair different versions of your code with different outputs.

Comment: You have no `return` statement in any of your `print_info` methods, so inside the `if..elif..else` block's `print` statement, it first outputs the newly-created car (from the `print` in `print_info`, and then outputs the return value of `print_info`, which is always `None` because you don't have a `return` value. There's no aggregation happening because you never append the cars to a list. Create a separate list of imports and domestic cars and only add a car to it if it's of the right type.

Comment: @SarahMesser would you mind showing me and example because when I do what you say I just get a bunch of errors. I created empty lists for my i_car & d_car then append them to ImportCar. I returned the values in print_info aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, brand: str, model: str, year: str, price: str, type: str):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.price = price
        self.type = type

    def print_info(self) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError('Override this in a subclass')


class ImportCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, brand: str, model: str, year: str, price: str, type: str, country: str, tax: str):
        super().__init__(brand: str, model: str, year: str, price: str, type: str)
        self.country = country
        self.tax = tax

    def print_info(self) -> None:
        print(self.brand, self.model, self.year, self.price, self.type, self.country, self.tax)


class DomesticCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, brand: str, model: str, year: str, price: str, type: str, state: str):
        super().__init__(brand, model, year, price, type)
        self.state = state

    def print_info(self) -> None:
        print(self.brand, self.model, self.year, self.price, self.type, self.state)


# initialize the lists of import and domestic cars
imports = []
domestics = []
with open("carsInStock.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines(): # The ".readlines()" is probably not necessary for a text file.
        # 1 line in file = 1 car
        val = line.split(). # fields are split on spaces
        if val[0] == "I":    # first field is whether an import or a domestic
            # Lots of arguments to ImportCar, so name them
            imports.append(ImportCar(brand=val[1], model=val[2], year=val[3], price=val[4], type=val[5], country=val[6], tax=val[7]))
            # Python almost never needs "break;" Avoid using it.
        elif val[0] == "D":
            domestics.append(DomesticCar(brand=val[1], model=val[2], year=val[3], price=val[4], type=val[5], state=val[6]))
        else:
            # Shouldn't reach this line, so be specific about what happened to get here
            print("ERROR: Skipping line which starts with", val[0])

print('All Domestic cars:')
for d in domestics:
    d.print_info()

print('All Imported cars:')
for i in imports:
    i.print_info()
```